# ImportError: No module named abc | Odoo 10 | Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I am getting this error,

```
  File "/home/mayank/Workspace/Odoo/v10/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1325, in __call__
    self.load_addons()
  File "/home/mayank/Workspace/Odoo/v10/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1346, in load_addons
    m = __import__('odoo.addons.' + module)
  File "/home/mayank/Workspace/Odoo/v10/odoo/odoo/modules/module.py", line 81, in load_module
    execfile(modfile, new_mod.__dict__)
  File "/home/mayank/Workspace/Projects/v10/smecen/odoo_10_plugins/api_nodejs/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    import models
  File "/home/mayank/Workspace/Projects/v10/smecen/odoo_10_plugins/api_nodejs/models/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    import keycloak
  File "/home/mayank/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keycloak/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .keycloak_admin import *
  File "/home/mayank/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keycloak/keycloak_admin.py", line 33, in <module>
    from .keycloak_openid import KeycloakOpenID
  File "/home/mayank/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keycloak/keycloak_openid.py", line 26, in <module>
    from jose import jwt
  File "/home/mayank/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jose/jwt.py", line 3, in <module>
    from collections.abc import Mapping
ImportError: No module named abc
```

Comment: You have to install abc or abstract module.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and **ask a question** when posting. Do not just show an error message. Also, please strongly consider upgrading Python. Python 2.7 has not been supported for over two years. It is equivalent to using Windows 7 as your OS.

Comment: Because the error came from code in a third-party library you installed, this tells you that the library does not support 2.7. You will have to upgrade if you want to use it.

Answer (score 5):

The `collections.abc` module was not added until Python 3.3.  You're running Python 2.7.  Python 2.7 is very, very old; you should strongly consider moving to Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

[python-jose V3.3.0](https://github.com/mpdavis/python-jose/releases/tag/3.3.0) Library removed support for python 2.7 & 3.5 so you can downgrade the python-jose to [version 3.2.0](https://github.com/mpdavis/python-jose/releases/tag/3.2.0)